# Site com navegação horizontal

Tags: html, css

Estou precisando fazer uma galeria de fotos no meu site. Essa galeria será no estile MetroUI, com imagens de tamanhos diferentes e a página deslizando na horizontal.

A página iria crescendo conforme o número de imagens salvas no banco de dados.

Dá para fazer isso apenas com CSS ou é necessário algum *script*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O MetroUI é um framework front-end que tem uma interface similar à do Windows 8.

Para a sua ocasião, a seção Tiles atende perfeitamente.

Um exemplo de uma página que utiliza o MetroUI

http://wsnippets.com/demo/windows8/

[image: Demonstração MetroUI]

O link para a documentação e download do framework é o seguinte:

https://metroui.org.ua/

Comment: Oi Victor, é exatamente isso. Você sabe alguma forma de fazer isso sem usar esse framework?

Comment: Se você precisa que as animações e os efeitos visuais sejam realmente próximos ao MetroUI, acredito que o menos custoso seria utilizar o framework, CSS e JavaScript puro lhe custariam o dobro ou o triplo do tempo para desenvolver. Há algum empecilho para que você utilize o framework?

Comment: Não, eu só queria que as imagens ficassem nesse formato e o efeito da página crescer na horizontal mesmo. Então, eu já estou utilizando um framework e nenhum medo de dar algum conflito entre eles.

Comment: Infelizmente utilizando puro CSS e JS não consigo te ajudar. Mas acredito que a chance de conflito entre os frameworks seja mínima, já utilizei o MetroUI com Bootstrap, jQuery e AngularJS sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Entendi. Eu estou utilizando o Materialize. Bom, vou tentar utilizar os dois juntos pra ver se não dá nenhum problema. Obrigado pela ajuda!